# UITapGestureRecognizer on a UIImageView inside an UIView only recognizes tap on small part of image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

My `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UIImageView` inside an `UIView` is only recognizing the tap on a small part of the image. I use the following code:

```
// definig inside @interface call inside .h
UITapGestureRecognizer* languageSelector;

// initializing inside initWithFrame
UIImage* langSelPopImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lang_EN_pop.png"];
langPopView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:langSelPopImg];
CGRect positioningHelper = CGRectMake(0, langSelPopImg.size.height, langSelImg.size.width, langSelImg.size.height);
langSelActiveLanguageView.frame = positioningHelper;
self.repositioningY = langSelPopImg.size.height;
self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, langSelImg.size.width, langSelImg.size.height + langSelPopImg.size.height);
self.clipsToBounds = YES;

// setting it up from inside an animateWithDuration/completion call:
languageSelector = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(languageSelectorTapped:)];
[langPopView addGestureRecognizer:languageSelector];
langPopView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// the method that only detects taps betwen y = 69 and y = 93
-(void)languageSelectorTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    CGPoint location = [languageSelector locationInView:languageSelector.view];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:langPopView];

    NSLog(@"x:%f/y:%f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thnx!!!

Comment: Try using UIButton with image instead of UIImageView + gesture recognizer.

Comment: @Roman: I could try that, thanx. But I like to know about the why-does-this-not-work-propperly, too.

Comment: @Omar: its all inside my class SelectBoxView : UIView

Comment: i mean why part of the image does not tap?

Comment: Check if your ImageView is in bounds of it's supreviews. Because it can be visible but not clickable in that case. Set all of it's superviews `clipsSubviewToBounds` (ot smth like this) property to `YES` and look what clips it.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have some control that might be overlapping and interfering (e.g. the code refers to controls/images that we don't see here, namely langSelImg and langSelActiveLanguageView ... not sure who contains/overlaps with whom, nor what these two are for at all)? Perhaps try temporarily removing some controls to make sure you don't have unintended interactions.

Comment: good idea, looks like overlapping for me. so an underlying image with gesture recognizer is intefering an overlying? I thought only what I see is what I can touch. how could I stop this interfefence? thnx!